# How does the Path of Exile ItemRenderer determine the items' rarity?

Tags: data-driven

This question is really specific to Path of Exile and their forum.

Basically, they render the items from a json object.

```
require(["PoE/Item/DeferredItemRenderer"], function(R) { (new R(JSON)) })
```

And the json of an item is of the form:

```
      {
         "verified":true,
         "w":1,
         "h":1,
         "icon":"http:\/\/webcdn.pathofexile.com\/image\/Art\/2DItems\/Rings\/Ring5.png?v=d645f9adfc012c52674c94d16b4292b2",
         "support":true,
         "league":"Default",
         "sockets":[

         ],
         "name":"Honour Grip",
         "typeLine":"Topaz Ring",
         "identified":true,
         "requirements":[
            {
               "name":"Level",
               "values":[
                  [
                     "41",
                     0
                  ]
               ],
               "displayMode":0
            }
         ],
         "implicitMods":[
            "+22% to Lightning Resistance"
         ],
         "explicitMods":[
            "Adds 4-48 Lightning Damage",
            "+8 to Evasion Rating",
            "+70 to maximum Life",
            "+35% to Cold Resistance"
         ],
         "frameType":2,
         "socketedItems":[

         ]
      }
```

I don't see the rarity of the item anywhere... How do you think they determine it? They could count the mods, but what if the object is not identified?

Comment: My guess is the `frameType` variable.

Comment: I guess you're right! I've checked and it seems like it works :) I had completely omitted this possibility, because I thought it was representing the "size" of the item. But the size is actually w & h, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the frameType property. I've tested this and changing it will change the colouring of the display box.

The possible values are:

- **0** Normal Item
- **1** Magic Item
- **2** Rare Item
- **3** Unique Item
- **4** Gem
- **5** Currency
- **6** Quest Item